# Magento 2.3 How to automate custom cron job from custom module?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cron, crontab, cronjobs

I am working on Cron from custom module to send email from custom cron job, I created it as below but the cron job is nor working on the server.

```
<?php
namespace Name\Module\Cron;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Name\Module\Model\MyModule;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Name\Module\Helper\Data;

class RfqCron {

protected $_logger;
protected $customerFactory;
protected $transportBuilder;
protected $helper;
protected $_myFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
    TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    Data $helper,
    \Name\Module\Model\ResourceModel\MyModule\CollectionFactory $myFactory
) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    $this->helper = $helper;
    $this->_myFactory = $myFactory;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_escaper = $escaper;
}
public function execute()
{
    try {
        $myCollection = $this->_myFactory->create();
        foreach ($rmyCollection as $myData) {
            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($myData->getCustomerId());
            $customerInfo = array(
                'name' => $customer['firstname'],
                'email' => 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'
            );

            $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
            $myExpireDate = $myData->getExpiryDate();
            if ($myExpireDate == $currentDate) {                    
                $templateId = $this->helper->getConfigValue('mysettings/my_customer_notification/customer_email_template_expire');
                $emailTemplateVariables = array(
                    'email' => $customerInfo['email'],
                    'name'   => $customerInfo['name'],
                    'msg'  => "email sent from cron"
                );
                $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
                $this->helper->sendEmailToCustomer(
                    $templateId, //email template id
                    $emailTemplateVariables, //variables
                    $customerInfo //receiver
                );

                $myData->setMyStatusId(4);
                $myData->save();
            }
        }
        $this->_logger->addDebug( "Message sent" );
        return;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        $this->_logger->addDebug( "Message not sent" );
        return;
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="name_module_cron_group"> 
        <job name="mycron" instance="Name\Module\Cron\MyCron" method="execute">
            <schedule> * www-data PHP /bin/magento cron:run</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to create your cron in `Cron` directory

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Cron/Mycron.php
```

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;

class Mycron
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface
    ) {
        $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
    }

    public function execute() {
        //Code here
        //$this->logger->debug('Vendor\Module\Cron\Mycron');

    }
}
```

then create cron_groups.xml in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/cron_groups.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/cron_groups.xsd">
    <group id="vendor_module_cron_group">
        <schedule_generate_every>1</schedule_generate_every>
        <schedule_ahead_for>4</schedule_ahead_for>
        <schedule_lifetime>2</schedule_lifetime>
        <history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
        <history_success_lifetime>60</history_success_lifetime>
        <history_failure_lifetime>600</history_failure_lifetime>
        <use_separate_process>1</use_separate_process>
    </group>
</config>
```

This will add entry in admin

Now for scheduling create crontab.xml in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/crontab.xml`. Schedule it according to your need

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="vendor_module_cron_group">

        <job name="vendor_module_cronjob_mycron" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\Mycron" method="execute">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>

    </group>
</config>
```

Comment: I did the same but still, the cron is not added in "Cron Schedule" table. is there something to check?

Comment: Check if magento cronjobs are set on your server. `crontab -e`. If magento cronjobs are not scheduled, then execute this command `php bin/magento cron:install`